# PHP mssql query with start and limit - append to query issue

Tags: php, sql-server

I usually code in PHP / MySQL but for this project have to use MSSQL.

The below logic would work in MySQL but because in MSSQL setting the limit is a much more complex query, its causing issues when I want to append to the query.  I have played around with the query to try and figure out how it should be but cannot get it working.  Please help.

```
    //get all products for shopkeeper
    if($limit == 0) {
        $prod_qry = "SELECT id, productName FROM products WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE shopkeeper = '$this->shopkeeper'";
    }
    if($limit > 0) {
        $prod_qry = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id, productName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row  FROM products WITH(NOLOCK)  WHERE shopkeeper='$this->shopkeeper'  ) a WHERE row > $start and row <= $limit";
    }
    if($hidden == 1) {
        $prod_qry .= " AND Hidden !='1'";
    }

    if($rating != 0) {
        $prod_qry .= " AND rating > '$rating'";
    }
```

****EDIT****
Ive figured it out, amended code below:

```
    $prod_qry = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id, productName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row  FROM products WITH(NOLOCK)  WHERE shopkeeper='$this->shopkeeper'" ;

    if($hidden == 1) {
        $prod_qry .= " AND Hidden !='1'";
    }

    if($rating != 0) {
        $prod_qry .= " AND rating > '$rating'";
    }       

    $prod_qry .= ") a ";    

    if($limit > 0) {
        $prod_qry .= " WHERE row > $start and row <= $limit";
    }
```

Comment: "but cannot get it working." Can you be more specific? What is the error message?

Comment: If you output the query before running it what does it look like ? is it formed correctly ?

Comment: this is the problem, I dont know how to form it correctly, Im unfamiliar with MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the question above with the answer.